# I Cannot Get If/Else Statement to Prove True with Scanner

Tags: java

Help. I'm new to Java programming so I'll try to make the best of your terms.
I was wondering how to get this program to register as true. When I type in "password" as an input, it does not execute any code from the "if" body. I also pasted this code in another class and it still doesn't work, regardless.

I've worked on this program for about a half an hour, and debugging it for twice as long. Please look through the coding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whileloop {

    public void whileloop1() {

        //DEBUG THIS PROGRAM! "password" does not work for input

        System.out.println("Please enter the password to continue: ");
        Scanner password = new Scanner(System.in);
        String passwordinput = password.nextLine();

        System.out.println("This is your entered password: " + passwordinput);

        if (passwordinput == "password") {

            System.out.println("Startup sequence has been iniciated.");
            System.out.println("System is working correctly.");

            //Terminate all here ---

         } else {

             System.out.println("Wrong password! Terminating program. /END");

        }

        System.out.println("Supressing the program's scanner!");
        password.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: `if ("password".equals(passwordinput))` instead.

Comment: either you are fast or you have a fast internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing string content in Java you use the *.equals()* method.
The == operator checks for reference equality, meaning, testing if they are both references of the same object.

So, in your case:

```
if(passwordinput.equals("password"))
```

Comment: Kk thanks, and concise. I would rep up both of your responses but I'm new so.. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been said many times, but I'll say it again, when comparing Strings in java, if you want to know if they point to the same reference use the `==` operator. if you want to check if they are equal in value use `.equals("somestringhere")`  In your case use `passwordinput.equals("password")`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry for being a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Since, in `Java` the line:

`String s;` declares a reference to a `String` object, unlike `C++`, which may declare an object of `String`.
So, the line if `(passwordinput  == "password")` compares the reference of `"password"` and reference of `passwordinput`, the result will be false.
So, use `if(passwordinput.equals("password")`, which compares the object `referenced` by `passwordinput` with `"password"`